# drag ImageView inside a WebView

Tags: android

:)
I'm adding an ImageView inside a WebView like this :

```
    void addImv(int in)
{
     imageView.setId(imageID);
     webComp.addView(imageView);

     Bitmap bitmap;
     File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     if(sd.canRead()){
         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/FMS/1/file"+in+".jpg");
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
         imageView.setMaxHeight(150);
         imageView.setAlpha(150);           

         imageView.bringToFront();          
     }
}
```

The photo is shown in the left top of the screen correctly.
Now I have this listener for touches on the imageView

```
    OnTouchListener listenTouch = new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {   
        return true;
    }
```

};

which works too. How can i set the position of the imageView? I've tried using imageView.setPadding and imageView.imageView.setLayoutParams but clearly I'm doing something really wrong as it force-closes. The imageView isn't defined in xml layout file. Thank you!

Comment: Adding your own views to a WebView doesn't sound like the intention of that control. Might be better to wrap both WebView and your own controls in some other layout view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
 OnTouchListener listenTouch = new OnTouchListener()
```

{

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{   
    imageView.offsetLeftAndRight((int)event.getX()-imageView.getWidth());
    imageView.offsetTopAndBottom((int)event.getY()-imageView.getHeight());
    webComp.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Use [AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.html) setting the correct X and Y co-ordinate or you can also use [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) OR [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for the purpose.

On how to use:

```
webComp.addView(imageView, <your params object>);
```