# How to drag an image in html file displayed using webview in android?

Tags: android, html, image, drag-and-drop, android-webview

I have an Android WebView loaded with a html file(actually stored in some folder under sdcard) that is having one/two/three image(s). Is it possible to drag-drop any one of those images?
If its possible, below are my doubts

1. When i drag an image from (x1,y1) place and drop it in another (x2,y2)place, How can i change the original source file code as the image place is changed ?
2. When i open the same html file in next time (using default html viewer or my app), i should see the image in (x2, y2) place. Isn't it possible ?
3. I tried this [drag ImageView inside a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620893/drag-imageview-inside-a-webview). But it is just adding an imageview to webview. (So, when i run the same app next time, i don't see the image in the place where i dropped it in first run.) But i need to drag an image presented in source html file. So After every drag-drop, Do i need to render the webview content and create a new html file to see the image in dropped location?
4. Is it possible to read the android-webview content? (like we read the web page content in java).

Can anyone clear my doubts and suggest me a better way if iam going/thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it possible (without using some not trivial tricks) to implement the drag and drop as you wish. for the other point's you raised - if the file is on your sd - why not just parse the html file and get the pictures positions and source link and use it to implement the drag and drop on your own? after all- the html file is an xml file which contains attributes which defines positions/links/images/text